# From apache to nginx: wordpress rewrite rule

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, nginx, permalinks

I'm migrating from apache2 to nginx. I cant figure out how to to rewrite this **rewrite rules** for wordpress.

This is actually my configuration file

```
server {
        listen 80;    
        root /usr/share/nginx/blog.com/public_html;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        server_name blog.com www.blog.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow ::1;
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ .php$ {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/blog.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

I'm using php5-fpm.

And this is the rule I would like to add :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Can you please help me? Thanks :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should read http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress

e.g.

```
    location /blog {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog)(/.*)$;
    }
```